# Convert PDF to byte array and viceversa android

Tags: java, android, pdf, byte

I'm trying to create an Android app able to upload and download PDF files to a server, I've already included in my code a method able to download a PDF from an URL such as "http://www.aaaa.com/myfile.pdf" and display it by using intent.
But I want to know if there is a way to encode a Pdf into a byte array and viceversa decode a byte array to PDF file (I'm using mongoDB)
Thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.nio.file.*;

Path pdfFilePath = Paths.get("/file/path/your_file.pdf");

// Read file to byte array
byte[] pdfByteArray = Files.readAllBytes(pdfFilePath );

// Write byte array to file 
Files.write(pdfFilePath , pdfByteArray);
```